# What does initial value mean in OpenGL's doc?

Tags: opengl

http://docs.gl/gl4/glVertexAttribPointer in this page, the description of parameter size, it said the initial value is 4, what does it mean? is it mean the value when invalid argument used?

Answer (score 3):

Most OpenGL functions set state into objects or the context. But that state exists *before* those functions get called. As such, that state has a value before the first time this function is called on a VAO.

That part of the documentation tells you what the initial value of the state that would be set by the `size` parameter is.